# Using extended Hex Codes in Xcode

Tags: xcode, post, hex

I am all very new to this and am trying to use extended hex codes (past the ascii characters of 127) that are generated by converting a decimal number to float number that is then being sent via a post command to a device to change a set point.

I am creating the hex codes by simply doing this,

```
- (void)dec2float:(id)sender
{
    NSString *dec = setPoint.text;
    float flt = [dec floatValue];
    unsigned char *bytes = (unsigned char *)&flt;
    sPoint01 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x", bytes[0]];
    sPoint02 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x", bytes[1]];
    sPoint03 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x", bytes[2]];
    sPoint04 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x", bytes[3]];
}
```

If the setPoint.text value is for example 23 this will make

```
sPoint01 = 00
sPoint02 = 00
sPoint03 = b8
sPoint01 = 41
```

These values then have to be sent to the device as a hexadecimal string which is being joined together as so,

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\x%@\\x%@\\x%@\\x%@",sPoint01, sPoint02, sPoint03, sPoint04];
```

but instead of "0000b841" being sent I am getting "00005c78 62385c78 3431". I am assuming this is because Xcode won't allow any hex code past 127 as if I try and type it in as so

```
@"\xb8"
```

Xcode tells me that the "Input conversion has stopped due to an input byte that does not belong to the input codeset UTF-8".

Am I going about this in the right way or have I managed to wander a long way down the wrong road?

Any help would be much appreciated and any advice welcomed.

Thank you in advance

Edit:

Hi,
Thanks for the reply this is the command that I am using to send the data to the controller hopefully it will be of help,

```
- (void)setACStatus:(id)sender
{    
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\x38\x00\x00\x00\x76\x11\x01\x00%@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1b\x00\x00\x00%@\x00%@%@\x00\x10\x00\x10%@%@%@%@%@\x00\x00\x00",
                      unitNumberString, onOffString, modeString, modeString2, sPoint01, sPoint02, sPoint03, sPoint04, 
                      fanSpeedString];

     postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];    

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@”%d”, [postData count];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@”http://10.38.140.9/cmd/”]];//<-- Controller address.
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/octet-stream" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if( theConnection )
    {
        webData = [NSMutableData data];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog (@"The Connection is NULL");
    }

    temp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",postData];
}
```

Thankyou.

Comment: How are you sending the strings to the device? That seems to be the issue. Also, there's a comma missing after the format string in your call to `stringWithFormat:`.

Comment: I have edited the above post with the POST command that I am using. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to create an `NSData` object from a string, but that you already know the bytes you want to the data object to contain. Instead of going through the extra step of creating a string and trying to convert that to a data object, just create the data object from your bytes, like so:

```
typedef struct postDataType = {
    unsigned char someData0[8];
    int unitNumberString;
    unsigned char someData1[33]; // or however many bytes it is
    unsigned char onOffString;
    // etc... rest of fields go here
} postDataType;
postDataType dataBytes = {
    {0x38, 0x00, 0x00 0x00, 0x76, 0x11, 0x01, 0x00},
    [unitNumberString intValue],
    // etc... fill in the rest of the fields here with the data you want
};
postData = [NSData dataWithBytes:dataBytes length:sizeof(dataBytes)];
```

Comment: Got it working, Sorry for the late replay but THANKYOU very much for your help.